Changing `locate` configuration so it indexes files in my home directory
I am the sole user of my macOS system (currently a Mac Mini M4 running macOS 15.1.1 Sequoia).
I would like to know if it's possible to (re)configure the builtin locate command and database to include files in my $HOME directory (/Users/luke).
I have read this answer and understand that out of the box, the program is configured to run as an unpriveleged user, and thus does not have access to the /Users/* directories. I wish to override this configuration, and am not concerned with security in this case.
I tried editing /etc/locate.rc and changing the SEARCHPATHS line to read:
SEARCHPATHS="/ /Users/luke"

I then ran
sudo /usr/libexec/locate.updatedb

But the result was an error which repeated several times:
shell-init: error retrieving current directory: getcwd: cannot access parent directories: Permission denied

...and no files in my home dir were indexed. Reading the manpage at man 8 locate.updatedb, I understand that there is a LaunchDaemon that typically runs once per week, configured by /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.locate.plist.
